# Static IP to Azure VMs

Tags: azure, ip, public

I have setup three virtual servers in Azure. They are three Windows 2008 R2 Servers.

They all have private and public IPs and I can access them from internet with no issue. I already setup private static IPs on them.

I would like to reserve public IPs on the VM machines so they do not change when server is shutdown or restart.

I am try to follow "How to add an ILPIP to an existing VM" by going to website https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/ but having problem following the shell command.

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName FTPService -Name FTPInstance 
| Set-AzurePublicIP -PublicIPName ftpip2 
| Update-AzureVM
```

They are standalone server. I will later install third party software. They are not running any ftp server and ftp instance. So the question is how can I assign public static IP to the VM machine

Thank you

Comment: What is the problem you are having? is there an error message? Do you know which of the three commands the error message is coming out of (save to a variable and create three separate commands to find out)

Comment: Since I do not have ftp Service running on server I am not sure if I can use the command. I would like to know if I can assign and static IP to virtual machine. It already has public IP I just want to reserve it. The server is plan windows server for now and no services are running.

Comment: The command has no reliance on whether any services are being offered from the IP address. You could just as well need a static IP address because of outgoing traffic that never offers any services. Once you have assigned an address you can then start to provide services from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a static PIP only a static VIP and the VIP will be assigned to a cloud service or if you are using ARM your load balancer not the VM itself.

As far as I know you can only assign a static VIP when you create the cloud service.

```
#get a new static IP    
New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName "MyReservedIP" –Location "AzureRegionName"

#create a new vm and cloud service and assign the static IP
New-AzureVM -ServiceName "NewServiceName" -ReservedIPName "MyReservedIP" -Location "AzureRegionName"
```

It is too long to post in the answer but I have a detailed explanation of the different types of IPs in Azure over [here](http://www.francoisdelport.com/2015/10/how-to-assign-a-public-static-ip-address-in-azure/).

Comment: Cloud Service >>> Does it refer to PAAS? I am using IAAS and have few servers in Azure.

Comment: Both, if you are using the legacy Azure API, Cloud Services are the containers for IAAS (VMs) and PAAS (Web/Worker Roles etc).

Comment: How can I find out -ServiceName. I setup all virtual machines using resource manager.